# How to launch multiple kernel in OpenCL, inside the program?

Tags: opencl, gpu

I'm trying to see the performance of the Opencl Programming model on GPUs, now while testing the Programming model, i have to launch the kernel by using `clEnqueueNDkernel()`, I'm trying to call this function multiple times, so that I can see how it performs when two or four concurrent kernels are launched.

I observe that the program is taking the same amount of time as launching one kernel, now I'm assuming that it is just running the kernel once, cause there is no way it takes the same amount of time to run two or four concurrent kernels.

Now I want to know how to launch multiple kernels on one GPU.

eg: I want to launch something like :

```
clEnqueueNDkernel()
clEnqueueNDkernel()
```

How can I do this?

Comment: By four concurrent kernels do you mean four same kernel codes or four different kernel codes? Also how much work there is within one kernel, is it just one addition of two values or lot of computation?

Comment: Four same kernels.  And the work load varies . as I m checking under various work load

Comment: If the computation amount is quite small, almost all of the time could be used to move data between host and device. This could be the reason why it takes the same amount of time for one and for four kernels. Try to make the load very huge compared to data transfer. Then it should take four times the time of one launch with four launches.

Comment: Did you include clFinish in your benchmark? If you didn't, you're only measuring the async enqueue time. Unless you're using multiple command queues or an out-of-order command queue, the kernels are definitely not running concurrently. You have to make some effort to get that to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, check if your Device supports concurrent kernel execution. Latest AMD & Nvidia cards do.

Then, create multiple command queues. If you enqueue kernels into same queue, they will be executed consecutively one after another.

Finally, check that kernels were indeed executed in parallel. Use profilers from SDK or OpenCL events to gather profiling info.

Comment: So u mean.. I shud use different queues in different clenqueuendkernel() .. That way it will run in parallel in same device

Comment: Yes. Queue by it's nature, means, that objects within will be accessed one by one. So, if you use single queue, kernels will be executed one after another.

Comment: It is possible to have multiple kernels from the same queue execute concurrently, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54013266/opencl-are-device-side-out-of-order-queues-also-parallel