# OpenCL: are device-side out-of-order queues also parallel?

Tags: queue, opencl

I'm doing some tests using device-side out-of-order command queues in combination with calls to enqueue_kernel to give them work.

My question is regarding the nature of the CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE flag set on the device-side queue when it is initialized.

As per the spec:

> "If the CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE property of a
>   commandqueue is set, then there is no guarantee that kernel A will
>   finish before kernel B starts execution. "

However, that wording leaves two (ambiguous) possibilities:

- kernel A starts, kernel B starts, kernel B finishes, kernel A finishes (they are launched in sequence, but run parallel, allowing for out-of-order completion/execution)
- kernel B starts, kernel B finishes, kernel A starts, kernel A finishes (they run in sequence, but are launched out of order)

Possibility 2 is what I'd expect, but Possibility 1 fits the description...so which assumption is correct? Or are they both possible? Is the behavior vendor/implementation specific?

Comment: I believe they're both possible and as you say certainly within spec. There's not really a good way to find out which is happening without vendor specific tooling.

Answer (score 1):

First option. The kernels are still "dispatched" in order. And if kernel A fills the machine with threads and leaves no room for kernel B, there'll be no difference. But if A doesn't fill the machine, and out_of_order is enabled, then kernel B will be dispatched right after A has finished dispatching its threads (i.e. its threads can still be executing). And the kernels can continue running in parallel.
Now it's possible the spec might have left it ambiguous as to the order of first dispatch, but since the dispatch of kernels is sequentially coming out of the CPU, I don't see any rational for why or how a vendor would allow possibility 2.